# Looping Audio in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, avaudioplayer

Im playing a sound in my app that I would like to loop.  My research into this hasnt quite sorted my issue.

my code .m

```
CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"ar4", CFSTR 
                                          ("wav"), NULL);


UInt32 soundID;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID (soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);
```

I think I need to put something like this in

```
numberOfLoops = -1;
```

But unsure how to implement in my code as I get undeclared error for numberOfLoops.  Some advice would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like this should do your problem:

```
    NSString* resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    resourcePath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingString:@"/YOURMUSICNAME.mp3"];
    NSLog(@"Path to play: %@", resourcePath);
    NSError* err;

    //Initialize our player pointing to the path to our resource
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                 [NSURL fileURLWithPath:resourcePath] error:&err];

    if( err ){
        //bail!
        NSLog(@"Failed with reason: %@", [err localizedDescription]);
    }
    else{
        //set our delegate and begin playback
        player.delegate = self;
        [player play];
        player.numberOfLoops = -1;
        player.currentTime = 0;
        player.volume = 1.0;
    }
```

Then if you want to stop it:

```
[player stop];
```

or pause it :

```
[player pause];
```

and also import it in your header file:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>.
```

You should to ofcourse declare it in your header, then synthesize it.

//.h and add the **bold** part:

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <**AVAudioPlayerDelegate**> {

```
AVAudioPlayer *player;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *player;
```

//.m

```
@synthesize player;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Ive followed your code and instructions but just getting errors everywhere, My code plays the sound fine and was hoping I could just adjust that so it loops the audio rather than playing it just once.

Comment: Your not initiatin it in your header and synthesizing it in your .m file thats why you are having errors. My code is working in mine. i was just suggestin this for easier approach

Comment: No prob :) just trying to help

Comment: Thanks so much dude! I replaced the path part with NSString* resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:loop
                                                             ofType:@"mp3"]; where loop is the string I am passing. Big props!