# Playing continuous audio in Iphone

Tags: ios, iphone

I have this piece  of code for playing audio, but once it is finished, I want to play the same audio again and again, I think I should use numberofloops=-1, but where I need to use this directly. Please help me.

```
#import "JetNapMusicPlayer.h"
    #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

    @interface JetNapMusicPlayer()
    @property(nonatomic,strong) AVQueuePlayer *avQueuePlayer;
    @end
    static JetNapMusicPlayer *sharedManager = nil;

    @implementation JetNapMusicPlaye
    #pragma mark Singleton Methods
    + (id)sharedManager {
        @synchronized(self) {
            if(sharedManager == nil)
                sharedManager = [[super alloc] init];
        }
        return sharedManager;
    }
    - (id)init {
        if (self = [super init]) {
    //        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

            MPRemoteCommandCenter *rcc = [MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter];
            MPRemoteCommand *playCommand = rcc.playCommand;
            [playCommand setEnabled:YES];
            [playCommand addTargetWithHandler:^MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus(MPRemoteCommandEvent *event) {
                [(JetNapMusicPlayer *)[JetNapMusicPlayer sharedManager] play];

                return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
            }];

            MPRemoteCommand *pauseCommand = rcc.pauseCommand;
            [pauseCommand setEnabled:YES];
            [pauseCommand addTargetWithHandler:^MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus(MPRemoteCommandEvent *event) {
                [(JetNapMusicPlayer *)[JetNapMusicPlayer sharedManager] pause];

                return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
            }];
        } 
        return self;
    }
    - (void)dealloc {
        [super dealloc];
    }
    -(AVPlayer *)avQueuePlayer
    {
        if (!_avQueuePlayer) {
            [self initSession];
            _avQueuePlayer = [[AVQueuePlayer alloc] init];
        } 
        return _avQueuePlayer;
    }
    -(void)initSession
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                                 selector:    @selector(audioSessionInterrupted:)
                                                     name:      AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification
                                                   object:      [AVAudioSession sharedInstance]]; 
        //set audio category with options - for this demo we'll do playback only
        NSError *categoryError = nil;
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&categoryError];
        if (categoryError) {
            NSLog(@"Error setting category! %@", [categoryError description]);
        }
        //activation of audio session
        NSError *activationError = nil;
        BOOL success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &activationError];
        if (!success) {
            if (activationError) {
                NSLog(@"Could not activate audio session. %@", [activationError localizedDescription]);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"audio session could not be activated!");
            }
        }   
    }
    #pragma mark - notifications
    -(void)audioSessionInterrupted:(NSNotification*)interruptionNotification
    {
        NSLog(@"interruption received: %@", interruptionNotification);
    }
    #pragma mark - player actions
    -(void) pause
    {
        [[self avQueuePlayer] pause];
    }
    -(void) play
    {
        [[self avQueuePlayer] play];
    }
    -(void) clear
    {
        [[self avQueuePlayer] removeAllItems];
    }
    #pragma mark - remote control events
    #pragma mark - Kony FFI
    + (BOOL)playMusic:(NSString *)filename artistname:(NSString *)artistname songname:(NSString *)songname {
        NSString *name = [filename stringByDeletingPathExtension];
        NSString *ext = [filename pathExtension];  
        AVPlayerItem *avSongItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:name] ofType:ext]]];  
        if (avSongItem) {
            [(JetNapMusicPlayer *)[JetNapMusicPlayer sharedManager] clear];
            [[[JetNapMusicPlayer sharedManager] avQueuePlayer] insertItem:avSongItem afterItem:nil];
            [(JetNapMusicPlayer *)[JetNapMusicPlayer sharedManager] play];     
            [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter].nowPlayingInfo = @{MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: songname, MPMediaItemPropertyArtist:artistname};   
        }
        return YES;
    }
    + (BOOL)stopMusic {
        [(JetNapMusicPlayer *)[JetNapMusicPlayer sharedManager] pause];
        [(JetNapMusicPlayer *)[JetNapMusicPlayer sharedManager] clear];
        return YES;
    }
    @end
```

Comment: This might be useful : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11376298

Answer (score 0):

To loop a song use below code after alloc init of avSongItem.

```
 avSongItem.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
```

More info : [Looping a video with AVFoundation AVPlayer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361145/looping-a-video-with-avfoundation-avplayer)

Also as mentioned in the link use notification.

avSongItem.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                       selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                           name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                         object:[avPlayer currentItem]];
```

this will prevent the player to pause at the end.

in the notification:

```
 - (void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification {
AVPlayerItem *p = [notification object];
[p seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
}
```

Comment: I added the code as mentioned below:          
AVPlayerItem *avSongItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:name] ofType:ext]]];               
    avSongItem.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;          But it is not working

Comment: Ok then after that use notification.

Comment: is JetNapMusicPlayer  is an instance of AVPlayer?
Also do settings as mentioned for AVPlayer instance and not on AVPlayerItem

Comment: Hi Anil, Actually I am a java developer, but i got this work and I do not know abc of Ios, so can you please edit my code and paste the modified one as your answer. I will be so thankful to you. Thanks in advance. I stuck in this issue for last two days..plzzz

Comment: Ok try these.
Method : playMusic
Before "if (avSongItem) ...." add the below 
[[JetNapMusicPlayer sharedManager] actionAtItemEnd] = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

Try this , if still didnt work then add notification

Comment: Notification code 

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                       selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                           name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                         object:[[JetNapMusicPlayer sharedManager]  currentItem]];

Comment: Then add below method: 
 - (void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification {
AVPlayerItem *p = [notification object];
[p seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
}